# Как создать библиотеку?

Tags: java, netbeans, библиотеки, jar

У меня есть три "куска" кода - интерфейс, абстрактный класс и класс. Класс наследует абстрактный класс, а абстрактный класс наследует интерфейс. Класс переопределяет и реализует все методы из интерфейса и Абстрактного Класса. Я хочу сделать из них библиотеку, а точнее пока только jar файл, чтобы импортировать их в свой код. Нужно ли мне делать их в разных проектах, но в одной раскладке(package)? Если да, то как мне их из разных проектов запилить в один jar-файл?

Или вообще можно не писать интерфейс и абстрактный класс, а оставить просто класс?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Разобрался сам

Все эти блоки кода надо положить в один проект.
Затем создать jar-файл.
После этого импортируем этот файл в [другой] проект.

Для NetBeans:
[Инструкция создания .jar-файла.](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/javase-deploy_ru.html)
[Инструкция по импорту .jar-файла в проект](http://www.sql.ru/forum/717334/kak-podkluchit-pakety-v-java)